# What are the differences between xsl:template which has only name attribute and xsl:function

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-3.0

I find they both can be called with parameters and return `xsl:value-of` and `xsl:sequence`, but what are the differences? Under what circumstances one should be used instead of the other for better? Do they have a small performance issue when used a lot?

Thank you very much.

BTW: my XSLT processor is saxon-he 9.8+.

Comment: `xsl:template` is supported in XSL 1.0, `xsl:function` is not. `xsl:template` can only be called with `call-template`, `xsl:function` can appear in an expression.

Comment: It occurred to me that there was a keyword "tunnel"  that can only used in templete's parameter, not in function's parameter. Is his use only visible to the progeny template called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some further, important differences are:

- a secondary result document can only be created in a template, not a in a function, see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#result-document-restrictions specifying "[ERR XTDE1480] It is a dynamic error to evaluate the `xsl:result-document` instruction in temporary output state." and "xsl:variable, xsl:param, xsl:with-param, xsl:function, xsl:key, xsl:sort, xsl:accumulator-rule, and xsl:merge-key always evaluate the instructions in their contained sequence constructor in temporary output state".
- inside of a function body, the focus(context item, context position, context size) is initially absent (see https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#function-result specifying "Within the sequence constructor, the focus is initially absent; this means that any attempt to reference the context item, context position, or context size is a dynamic error"), this means, any item not stored in global variables need to be passed as arguments to the function
- in Saxon (9.8 and 9.9 at least), while the API (http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/s9api/Xslt30Transformer.html#callFunction-net.sf.saxon.s9api.QName-net.sf.saxon.s9api.XdmValue:A-) has been extended to support the new XSLT 3 feature to start processing by calling a named (and public) function, the command line interface doesn't allow this as it has no new command line option for this

Comment: Thanks, they're so professional. Excuse me, for the second sentence of the first item, Does it mean that  ":xsl:variable,  ... xsl:merge-key" are same usage way both in template and function?  regretfully for last item,  I  don't know about it and can't understand what situations to use the API callFunction＼callTemplate.

Comment: The third point I have mentioned refers to the options the XSLT 3 specification gives you to start/invoke a transformation, it mentions "apply-templates invocation" (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#invoking-initial-mode), "call-template invocation" (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#invoking-initial-template) and "function call invocation" (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#invoking-initial-function). Saxon 9 (9.8 and 9.9) at the API level you use with Java or C# gives you all three options, but at the command line only the first two options.

Comment: The sentence I quoted which mentions `xsl:variable, xsl:param, ..., xsl:merge-key` indeed says that in all these the use of `xsl:result-document` to create a secondary result document will not work.

Comment: I see the sentence, thanks. For the 3rd point, I understand too, but I have another question, can  "call-template invocation", "function call invocation" be used in c/c++ saxon version?

Comment: Sure, the API documentation at https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc/html/classXslt30Processor.html has the relevant methods like `callTemplateReturningFile/callTemplateReturningString/callTemplateReturningValue` as well as `callFunctionReturningFile/callFunctionReturningString/callFunctionReturningValue`.

Comment: Ok, I'am stupid. Can a stylesheet call a function writen in c/c++? I saw that usage in java. Adding a xmlns to the java pakage, then use a java function with the xmlns prefix.

Comment: @cmf41013, can you raise that as a separate question? http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/documentation/index.html#!extensibility/extensions_cpp has some explanation on that but I have never used that, if that documentation doesn't help you then raise a specific question as to what you have tried, how it failed, with the tags for `saxon` and `saxon-c`. Or use the Saxon-C help forum of Saxonica directly https://saxonica.plan.io/projects/saxon-c/boards.

Comment: Hi, today I find that these xpath functions `document-uri()` and `fn:base-uri()`  can't be used in a `xsl:function`, otherwise there wiil be an error "There is no context item"

Comment: @cmf41013, well, the second item in the list "inside of a function body, the focus(context item, context position, context size) is initially absent ..." covers that. As said there, any item not bound in a global parameter or variable needs to be passed in as a parameter to your function so you can use e.g. `base-uri($param)` or use an XSLT instruction to change/set the context in the function e.g. `<xsl:for-each select="$param">...<xsl:value-of select="base-uri()"/>...</xsl:for-each>`.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO there are several differences:

- You can use XSL functions in an XPath. That can't be done with templates.
- You need to call functions explicitly. Templates are applied implicitly (no need for `call-template`)
- Templates are supported in earlier versions of XSL

Regarding performance: don't bother, until you have identified a performance issue. As Donald Knuth sais: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil". Just use whatever is suited best for the purpose.

Comment: `Templates are applied implicitly` - not the ones that only have a `name`, Those can only be `call-template`d.

Comment: which is the better choice when we translate the current element and his descendant?

Comment: @cmf41013: I prefer templates, but it might be that I'm just more used to it.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT is a two-language system; XSLT and XPath share the same data model, but they are not fully composable. You can nest XPath expressions within XSLT instructions, but you can't do the reverse.

To compensate for the lack of composability, many "flow of control" operations are duplicated across the two languages. XSLT has conditional instructions, XPath has conditional expressions. XSLT has a mapping operator (`xsl:for-each`), so does XPath (`!`). XSLT can declare variables (`xsl:variable`), so can XPath (`let`). XSLT has a call mechanism (`xsl:call-template`), so does XPath (function calls). These duplications exist to reduce the inconvenience of switching between the two languages for common simple tasks. The duality between function calls and named templates is just one example.

More specifically, `xsl:function` was introduced in XSLT 2.0 as a way of enabling XSLT constructs (`xsl:number` and `xsl:sort` are classic examples) to be invoked from within XPath expressions, thus improving the composability of the two languages even though direct syntactic nesting is not possible.

Comment: It' so abstruse for me . Does it happen that the more frequently to switch between the two languages, the lower performance?

Comment: I seem to understand why xsl:function come out. Foremost, called by xpath for acrossing?

Comment: Performance depends on the implementation. Because the languages share the same data model, there should be no need for any run-time overhead when calling one from the other -- though it could happen if the XSLT engine and the XPath engine were developed independently and have different internal data representations.